# Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:4567

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I created a simple ruby/sinatra application following a tutorial from tutsplus. I have done everything as instructed but when I go to "localhost:4567", I don't see what I expect, instead I am greeted with the error message:

"Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:4567"

Is there something I need to do to this port? 
EDIT: 
With some help i figured I should have used port 9393. But now i get this error: [error](http://gyazo.com/e5d44e59821908afdc637c82d8007722)

and this is the code in my recall.rb app:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'datamapper'

DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/recall.db")  

class Note  
  include DataMapper::Resource  
  property :id, Serial  
  property :content, Text, :required => true  
  property :complete, Boolean, :required => true, :default => false  
  property :created_at, DateTime  
  property :updated_at, DateTime  
end  

DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!

get '/' do  
  @notes = Note.all :order => :id.desc  
  @title = 'All Notes'  
  erb :home  
end
```

EDIT again:
SOLVED using

`require data_mapper`

Comment: Can you share a link to the tutorial or post your code here and the commands you're using to run the server?

Comment: @mbratch: how do I do that?

Comment: @alfonso: tut: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/singing-with-sinatra-the-recall-app-2/
I am stuck at the "Layout" heading...

Comment: can you provide some output, ie. when you execute it... Sinatra by default prints some info at the start. Also some ruby code won't do any harm.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to ask: did you get a message when you ran `ruby basics.rb` that says Sinatra has "taken the stage" on port 4567?

Comment: @mbratch: basics.rb was another excercise I did...had but when i run the 'ruby basics.rb' i got the "sinatra has taken the stage" msg...but not when i run 'ruby recall.rb' which is another app.

Comment: @Kira: this is the app code: http://pastebin.com/QV7SNByc

Answer (score 2):

According to the [png file](http://i40.tinypic.com/2gx1uf6.png) you posted in your other comment, your Webrick server is saying it started up on port 9393. So you should try accessing the app via `http://localhost:9393`.

Comment: that's right! i did that and there's a new development: [link](http://gyazo.com/e5d44e59821908afdc637c82d8007722) and now i'm totally lost!

Comment: i already installed sinatra and datamapper with this command `gem install sqlite3 datamapper dm-sqlite-adapter ` if that helps.

Comment: Now it's attempting to access your app, but your app has an error somewhere. You'll ultimately need to show your code if you want more hope. I suggest editing your original post and including more information. I'm assuming you've stepped off of what the tutorial does and added more things. Did you get a message when you installed the gem saying `datamapper` installed successfully? Try `gem list datamapper`.

Comment: @Siaw this is the correct answer to the question.  It should be accepted, and you should open another question if you have a different problem.

Comment: @mbratch when i run `gem list datamapper` i get `*** LOCAL GEMS ***

datamapper (1.2.0)`

Comment: @bdares i have posted my code in the starting post but here it is again [the app code](http://gyazo.com/cd8fa2556568647e0df35f2b7c6a277a)

Answer (score 1):

Remember to start your server with `shotgun recall.rb`.

Comment: Look at the picture carefully, and read the output. Like @mrbratch says, it's telling you 9393.

Comment: solved! this is quite strange or i don't understand it. in my recall.rb i changed `require 'datamapper` to `require data_mapper` but i don't have any "data_mapper" gem but it worked. the gem i have is name "datamapper" so this is quite confusing.